# How to add composite foreign key in data annotation for Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, composite-key

I am working on ASP.NET application with Entity Framework 6. I have already database and I am using Code First existing Database approach.

I am two table and second table has Foriegn key along with its own primary key. I have used Column order but still getting following error. I have search online, tried different combination but still getting error.

```
'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity_Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role  'Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity_Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity_Source' in relationship 'Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity_Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

### Class A

```
 [Table("Sys_Nav_Function")]
 public class Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity
 {
    public Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity()
    { }


    [Key]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Title")]
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Hierarchy Level")]
    [Display(Name = "Hierarchy Level")]
    public int Hierarchy_Level { get; set; }


    public Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sys_Nav_FunctionInActionEntity> Sys_Nav_FunctionInActionEntity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sys_Nav_FunctionInControllerEntity> Sys_Nav_FunctionInControllerEntity { get; set; }
}
```

### Class B

```
 [Table("Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy")]
public class Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity
{
    public Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity()
    {

    }


    [Key, Column(Order =0)]
    public int Hierarchy_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity"), Column(Order =1)]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    public int Parent_Function_ID { get; set; }

    public Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[Table("Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy")]
public class Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity
{
    public Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity()
    {

    }


    [Key, Column(Order =0)]
    public int Hierarchy_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Function_ID"), Column(Order =1)]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    public int Parent_Function_ID { get; set; }

    public Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The foriegn key you have in class B is linked to the table and not to the property.

I believe the above code should give you the correct result

Comment: I have tried as you have suggested and I am getting following error now;

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The property 'Function_ID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the ForeignKey attribute should be set on the navigation property:

```
[Table("Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy")]
public class Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity
{
    //...
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Function_ID")]
    public Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity { get; set; }
}
```

If Parent_Function_ID is also a foreign key to the same table, you can do it the same way.

Also, in the first class:

```
public Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity { get; set; }
```

should be a collection (if I understood the probem correctly)

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'App.DAL.Entities.Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity' and 'App.DAL.Entities.Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: try this in the first class :

[InverseProperty("Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity")]
 public ICollection<Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity> Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

I have remove composite key, I have tried different combination but no luck, however its working by using same key as foreign key and also changed in database.

```
[Table("Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchy")]
public class Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity
{
    public Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchyEntity()
    {

    }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity")]
    [Required]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    public int Parent_Function_ID { get; set; }

    public Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity Sys_Nav_FunctionEntity { get; set; }
}
```